# Write a program that checks if a 2-D integer array is a square array, meaning, if its rows and columns are equal. My code is below

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, 2d, variable-length-array

```
package Homeworks;

public class HomeWork85 {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[][] a = {
            {1,1,1,2},
            {1,1,1},
            {1,1,1}
        };

    int[][] b = {
            {1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1}
        };

    for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<a[i].length-1;j++) {
            if (a.length==a[j].length) {
                System.out.println("It is a square");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Not a square");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: My result: Not a square
Not a square
Not a square
It is a square
It is a square
It is a square
It is a square

Comment: ...And the question is ?

Comment: It doesn't give me a single "its a square" or its not a square. it gives me both it is a square and its not a square. So i do not know what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your logic is correct, you are doing redundant checking. What you should ideally do is you have the row length using `a.length`. You should iterate through each row once, using `a[j].length` and check whether the number of rows is equal to the number of values in each row(number of columns).

If not, then print 'not a square' and break out of the loop. Keep a flag indicating that the loop was stopped explicitly. If not, the flag remains the same and you can conclude that it was a square.

```
int flag = 0;
for (int j=0;j<a.length;j++) {

        if (a.length != a[j].length){
            System.out.println("Not a Square!");
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }

}   
if (flag == 0){
    System.out.println("It is a Square");
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. why are you making flag=1 and flag==0? What do these numbers represent?

Comment: Flag, in general, is an indicator of whether an event has occurred or not. In this case, there can be two outcomes, either its a square or it's not. So in my for loop, I'm checking whether there is any mismatch between rows and column length (Not a square). So if this event occurs I set some value to flag (1). If the value is 1, It means a decision has already been made that its not a square and I do not need to process further. I just used 1 and 0 for convenience, it can be any number or boolean as well.